# Where can we find the html code of the new custom master page

Tags: custom-masterpage, design

I created a new custom master page.

In the developer tools of IE I am able to see the code with many divs with different classes, but when I open the custom_master_page.html, I can't find any of those codes.

If I want to introduce a new div into the master page layout I am unable to do it because I couldn't identify where exactly the code lies. The html page of the master page did not contain any of the code that I am viewing in the developer tools on the browser of the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Master pages are written in aspx - they are mostly server-side code that will get processed when a page is requested.

Depending on where you want to put this new div, you may or may not be able to add it via master page. It takes a lot of practice to know what to do with the SP master page. Try playing around with it, or post what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to bring in a new div in s4-bodyContainer,when I opened the source code in developer tools of the browser am able to see the complete html code.But when I want to locate the file containing the html code,where can I exactly find it in my sitecollection? @hamboy